# Copy/Paste in Windows 7 does not keep layout anymore

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, layout

Since a short while, when I select something in, say, Firefox, Chrome or my mail client, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or use right-mouse-button and select copy), hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in another application that supports copying with layout (like MS Word), **the layout is not copied**.

At first I thought no complex content could be copied at all anymore, but programs still seem to manage to get complex content on the clipboard (i.e., hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> still works).

But, trying copy and paste inside the same program, for instance MS Word, it doesn't remember the layout, it just pastes as plain text always. In MS Excel, it's even weirder, normally you see a dashed bar around your copied content, but this bar only flashes momentarily. The "paste options" only show the "paste as text" option, the others aren't there.

I tried restarting and I am up to date with the latest fixes of Windows Update.
Any other ideas I could try?

Answer (score 4):

Using different keywords when searching, I finally landed on [this page in Microsoft Office 2010 Forums](http://www.microsoftoffice2010forums.com/general-microsoft-office-2010-discussion/help-i-on), which explained the problem from an MS Word perspective. It appears that Skype Click To Call, which apparently automatically installs itself with Skype, causes this problem.

I removed it and suddenly everything works as expected again, I can do normal Ctrl-C/V in every program and the layout of the complex content remains as it should. MS Excel is also acting normally again.

Comment: Nice catch! Have a +1 :)